# Difference in positioning a using block

Tags: c#, using, ref

What is the difference between :

Case 1:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
using(reader)
{
     while(reader.read())
     {
         DoSomething(ref reader);
     }
}
```

Case 2 :

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
     while(reader.read())
     {
         DoSomething(ref reader);
     }
}
```

Case 1 : Doesn't produce any compiler errors but a warning line is shown under the reader variable inside the `using` block and the warning says :

*Possibly incorrect assignment to local 'variable' which is the argument to a `using` or `lock` statement. The `Dispose` call or unlocking will happen on the original value of the local.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhdyhfk6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Case 2 : It produces a compiler error, due to the restricting the `using` variable to readonly access.

Neglecting the need to use `ref`, does this mean that in Case 1, the `reader` variable won't be disposed, or at least disposed "as expected" ? Why is Case 1 doesn't produce any compiler errors but Case 2 does ?

Comment: Basically, you cannot / should not use `ref` here.

Comment: Why are you passing this local by reference? What is `DoSomething()` assigning to the parameter?

Comment: @cdhowie Neglecting the reason, as i already agree it is pointless, and DoSomething doesn't even assign to the parameter, lets say it calls GetInt32(0) on the passed reader

Comment: @SirajMansour Then the fix is to not mark that parameter as `ref`, as it doesn't require pass by reference semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables declared within a `using` statement are read-only (they cannot be assigned after initialization).
Therefore, you cannot pass them as `ref` parameters, since the point of `ref` parameters is to be assigned.

In your first example, the variable is not *declared* in the `using` statement, so it isn't read-only.

It gives a compiler warning for the same reason that the second variable is read-only.

The reason is that (as the warning states) the `using` statement will only dispose the variable's *original* value.

Comment: Yes i already knew this, but in case 1, no compiler errors are produced even though the reader variable is passed as a ref parameter.

Comment: @SirajMansour In your question you say that case 2 produces a compiler error, now you say it does not?  Which is it?

Comment: @SirajMansour No errors are produced because `reader` is not read-only.  When you *declare* the variable within a `using` block, it is implicitly read-only.  That is why you get an error in the second case.

Comment: @SLaks, i see. Now we go back to my second question.
"the using statement will only dispose the variable's original value."
This is confusing me, will my reader be disposed as expected ? or there is something slippery here ?

Comment: @SirajMansour If you assign a different reader to the parameter from within `DoSomething()` that reader will *not* be disposed.  The original reader you started with will be disposed.